# PHP using JsonSerializable::jsonSerialize() over inheritance

Tags: php

Below are the classes used:
My base model class:

```
<?php
namespace model;

abstract class Model implements \JsonSerializable {
    public function jsonSerialize() {
        $vars = get_object_vars ( $this );
        return $vars;
    }
}
```

My custom model class:

```
<?php
namespace some\namespace;

use model\Model;

final class MyOwnModel extends Model {
    private $my_var;
    //also has public getters and setters
}
```

`json_encode()` is not able to provide {"my_var":"my_data"}

Comment: private $my_var; it's private hence not accessible outside it's own scope.

Comment: The very purpose of [`JsonSerializable::jsonSerialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php) is to let the class do something better than calling [`get_object_vars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php). [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) already does something similar to `get_object_vars()` when it encodes an object of a class that does not implement [`JsonSerializable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php).

Comment: I am new to php, what will the solution be in that case?

Comment: @MaartenvanMiddelaar Thank you, this explained a gotcha I just hit! I extended a class that already implemented JsonSerialize the way I wanted to, but the extra properties of my child class were private, so they were never included in the JSON output. Now I can be at peace knowing **why** re-implementing JsonSerialize in the child class solved the problem.